# Asked to schedule interview in SF while I'm visiting, no response for two weeks and I'm here already. What to do?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I've been in the run for this out-of-state startup job (< 10 people) in SF and went through 2 rounds: phone and 20+ hour paid project. When I told them that I'd be in San Francisco starting from today until Monday night, they asked if I could schedule a visit to their SF office. I said yes of course, but now this was two weeks ago and no response, despite a follow-up email a week before I came here.

Would it be worth giving them a call? I have a feeling they moved on since they would have responded already. They didn't ask me to come to SF. I came to SF for vacation and thought it'd be convenient for both of us to meet in-person.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Consider what might happen if you call or don't call, for both them no longer being interested or there being some other reason they haven't responded. That should make the choice fairly clear (what do you have to lose?).

Answer (score 8):

> Would it be worth giving them a call?

**Definitely** worth giving a call to them, if it means a chance to landing an offer you like. You say you already had a phone interview, so you have at least one number to try calling.

I would do it ASAP, and in future situations I suggest you don't wait two weeks to reach out to them when time is a factor.

Comment: +1 Definitely should have tried calling earlier.

Comment: Gave them a call, went straight to voicemail. Hopefully they get back but at this point, I think it's entirely in their court now.

Comment: @Jason seems like so... perhaps (just guessing) the position is no longer available, but I am probably wrong. Do you have any other way to contact them? Perhaps you know their address to their offices or similar...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Their address in an e-mail signature, but showing up to their office unannounced may be too intrusive?

Comment: Perhaps it could be a bit intrusive, but you could consider just checking if they still have their offices on such address, that way you can discard the possibility that they have moved. Do consider giving them a call later (don't know what time is over there but when you get a chance and it's a decent hour)